# Fill empty spaces with sibling elements using CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm trying to create a mosaic of images, but i'm having a hard time positioning them.

The elements i'm using are floated left, have different sizes and are following a specific display order. Is there a way of doing it using only CSS?

This is how i want it to be:

[image]

And this is how it is right now:

[image]

Finally, what i've coded so far:

```css
span {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.mosaic_wrapper {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1075px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.mosaic_wrapper div {
  float: left;
  width: 100%
}

.mosaic_wrapper div .image_wrapper {
  width: 48%;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.5% 0.5%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mosaic_wrapper div .image_wrapper a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.mosaic_wrapper div .image_wrapper a:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.mosaic_wrapper div .image_wrapper a:hover span.bg {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.mosaic_wrapper div .image_wrapper a img {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}

.mosaic_wrapper div .image_wrapper a span.bg {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #999999, #222222);
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  display: block;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.mosaic_wrapper div .image_wrapper a div.text {
  color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

.mosaic_wrapper div .image_wrapper a div.text span {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.mosaic_wrapper div .image_wrapper a div.text span.parent {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.mosaic_wrapper div .image_wrapper a div.text span.dept {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.1;
}

.mosaic_wrapper div .image_wrapper a div.text span.desc {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="mosaic_wrapper">
  <div>
    <div class="image_wrapper" style="width: 58%;">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/623x400">
        <div class="text">
          <span class="parent">Test</span>
          <span class="dept">Test</span>
          <span class="desc">Test</span>
        </div>
        <span class="bg"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="image_wrapper" style="width: 40%;height: 800px;">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/430x800">
        <div class="text">
          <span class="parent">Test</span>
          <span class="dept">Test</span>
          <span class="desc">Test</span>
        </div>
        <span class="bg"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="image_wrapper" style="width: 28%;">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x400">
        <div class="text">
          <span class="parent">Test</span>
          <span class="dept">Test</span>
          <span class="desc">Test</span>
        </div>
        <span class="bg"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="image_wrapper" style="width: 29%;">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x400">
        <div class="text">
          <span class="parent">Test</span>
          <span class="dept">Test</span>
          <span class="desc">Test</span>
        </div>
        <span class="bg"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="image_wrapper" style="width: 100%;">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1075x400">
        <div class="text">
          <span class="parent">Test</span>
          <span class="dept">Test</span>
          <span class="desc">Test</span>
        </div>
        <span class="bg"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a float:right to the 430x800 mosaic;

```
<div class="image_wrapper" style="width: 40%;height: 800px;float:right">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/430x800">
    <div class="text">
      <span class="parent">Test</span>
      <span class="dept">Test</span>
      <span class="desc">Test</span>
    </div>
    <span class="bg"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can add an id attribute to the 430x800 mosaic like id="rightMosaic"and create this style for it:

```
.mosaic_wrapper div .image_wrapper#rightMosaic{
  float: right;
}
```

And of corse remove it from the inline style

Comment: That worked, man. Thanks for your answer! I want to try making it without changing common elements CSS first. If i can't do it, i'll surely take your suggestion as answer and combine it with `nth-of-child()` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I would use flex rows and columns to lay this out. Adjusted your image dimensions a little so everything will line up

```css
* {
  margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.col {
  flex-direction: column;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex" style="margin: 0 0 12px;">
  <div class="flex col" style="margin: 0 12px 0 0;">
    <div style="margin: 0 0 12px 0;">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/612x400">
    </div>
    <div class="flex">
      <div style="margin: 0 12px 0 0;">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x400">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x400">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/430x812">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1054x400">
</div>
```

Comment: I have applied `flex` to the container and `flex` / `flex-direction` to columns, but they're lining up horizontaly. Can you tell me what am i doing wrong? I see that you changed the HTML structure as well. Would i have to make these changes?

Comment: @doutriforce yeah you would need to use this structure to group elements together into rows/columns.

Comment: @doutriforce and you'll need to share your code if you want me to give you feedback.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help! I didn't want to have to change HTML structure, cause all of this is inside an asp.net repeater and i'm trying to create like, types (sizes) of "banners" that will fit dinamically to the page. Here's the updated code with your suggestion. https://jsfiddle.net/1nub8j9q/

Comment: @doutriforce cool you're welcome. I would change your html structure even if you wanted to use floats.

Comment: What's wrong with the structure? And how could i place different div's in different places, with specific strutctures, depending on the banner type?

Comment: @doutriforce it would be a lot easier if you put 1,3,4 in an element floated left, then float 2 left, and display 5 normally underneath them. "how could i place different div's in different places, with specific strutctures, depending on the banner type" I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144868/discussion-between-doutriforce-and-michael-coker).